# Condition on output of Lyapunov equation being positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, positive-definite

I have Matlab code that solves the Lyapunov equation $$AX + XA^T + Q = 0$$ for a 3-D array of matrices, $A$, using the Matlab function `lyap(A,Q)`. My problem is that sometimes the resultant matrix, $X$, is positive definite and sometimes it is not. My question is given that the matrix $Q$ is positive definite, what is the condition on $A$ that the resultant matrix, $X$, is always positive definite?

Answer (score 3):

Given $Q>0$, $X$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ is stable (i.e., all the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts).

This is the Lyapunov Theorem. See thm 2.2.1 in the book "Topics in Matrix Analysis".

In fact, the above condition may still be true even if $Q$ is merely positive semi-definite. But in that case $(A,Q)$ must be controllable (If $Q$ is positive definite then $(A,Q)$ is controllable). For proof see thm 2.4.7 in the book. You can also have a look at this [post](https://shiyuzhao1.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/awwath-prove-positive-stability-of-a/).

Comment: (+1) This is also theorem 12.4 (Lyapunov test for controllability) in section 12.3 in the 2nd edition of the book *Linear Systems Theory* by Joao P. Hespanha.